# is it possible to host a microsoft access database on a dedicated server?

Tags: ms-access

i just want to ask if it is possible or any alternatives may do so.. cause we do have a project wherein we need a dedicated server to host our database..the question is, is it possible that a Microsoft database access will do so?..or any alternatives..thanks for the replies..appreciate it :D

Comment: Why do you feel you need a dedicated server?   All my clients have the Access database files on a regular file server.

Comment: we need a dedicated server so that everytime the client wants to access the application..its up 24/7.

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to answer the question. If you're thinking you're going to have a hosted server and access your database over HTTP, then you're fooling yourself -- you can't, unless you write a web app as the interface to the MDB/ACCDB stored on the server. If you mean a file server, then that's a very weird thing to not simply have inhouse for the users. You need to explain your actual scenario before anybody can give a useful answer.

Comment: why would an inhouse file server be down? Even my laptop stays on 24/7 and isn't rebooted but once every several weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/sqlserver).
It's designed for scenarios like yours (among many others)

Comment: What exactly is his scenario?  I couldn't gleam anything about what the needs of his solution are other then somewhere for the database to live.

Comment: @Christopher: A database used by multiple people (I assume)

Comment: 2 people? 20? 200? 2000?  Just saying...   people used to write deparmental applications all the time using access.

Comment: Anybody using Access with more than one person accessing it at the same time is setting himself up for trouble.

Comment: Femaref, I have a number of clients happily running multiple users against an Access database.  One of them had 25 users in all day long.   Last time I visited them they had 600K records in one table.  No troubles other than a wonky Citrix server caused two corruptions.  Which was fixed in a very short period of time with no data loss.  Once we took out that particular Citrix server out of the rotation all was fine for years.

Comment: I'm primarily an InstallShield Consultant and I still get plenty of people coming to me wanting installers for solutions based on legacy platforms.  VB6, Delphi, PowerBuilder, FoxPro, Paradox, Access.   This stuff is still being used.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply! I just asked this so that i can use it for my study..i'm a graduating student taking up IT, and for our study.. we need a dedicated server hosting?.. so preferably sql over access?..what do you think?..can you point out what would be the difference of the 2 technologies.advantages or disadvantages on a dedicated server?

Answer (score 0):

People ( for better or for worse ) used to ( probably still ) do this all the time.  If it's a small database accessed by only a few users it'll work fairly well.

I don't know what you are using it for but a modern day equivalent would be SQL Server Express or maybe SQL Server Compact edition.

Comment: So long is few is defined as less than 25 or 50 users sure, no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply! I just asked this so that i can use it for my study..i'm a graduating student taking up IT, and for our study.. we need a dedicated server hosting?.. so preferably sql over access?..what do you think?..can you point out what would be the difference of the 2 technologies.advantages or disadvantages on a dedicated server?